# Grab scenario information in Before and After hooks?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, hook, gherkin, scenarios

Right now I am trying to grab the information from the current scenario (description, file path, name, etc.). I try to get the scenario information in the before hook like this

```
Before do |scenario|
    puts scenario.name
    puts scenario.description
    #etc.
end
```

however things like scenario.description are not available for use. This is because when running in both Before and After hook, scenario is being called as `Cucumber::RunningTestCase::Scenario` instead part of the core AST module, like feature. I want to be able to access the scenario from `Cucumber::Core::Ast::Scenario` and `Cucumber::Core::Ast::OutlineTable::ExampleRow`, where values like current scenario description is available. Is it possible to get access to `Cucumber::Core::Ast::Scenario` in before and after hooks instead of `Cucumber::RunningTestCase::Scenario`, or another way to grab information like scenario name, description, file path, etc.? This is using the latest version of the cucumber and cucumber core gems (2.4 and 1.5). In addition, I am also no longer to able to access information about the current step, and step count.

Answer (score 2):

```
Before do |scenario|
  all_sources = scenario.outline? ? scenario.scenario_outline.all_source : scenario.all_source
end
```

From the all_source variable you will have access to several objects from ::Ast

Scenario Outline:

- Cucumber::Core::Ast::Feature
- Cucumber::Core::Ast::ScenarioOutline
- Cucumber::Core::Ast::Examples
- Cucumber::Core::Ast::ExamplesTable::Row:
- Cucumber::Core::Ast::ExpandedOutlineStep

Scenario:

- Cucumber::Core::Ast::Feature
- Cucumber::Core::Ast::Scenario
- Cucumber::Core::Ast::Step

From these you should be able to get data about file path, descriptions, comments, tags, hooks, line numbers and so on.